# What does this delegate subscription actually do

Tags: c#, delegates

I found this type of event subscription inside a project and I can't figure it out what it actually does. Bellow I have a full class implementation to test the scenario and the lines that raise questions are `_onScroll += _ => _onScroll3?.Invoke();` and `_onScroll2 += () => _onScroll3?.Invoke();`.
After testing the code all I can conclude is that `_onScroll` and `_onScroll2` somehow copy `_onScroll3` subscribers, but why is there a call to `Invoke` method?

```
public class TestEvent
{
    private event Action<int> _onScroll;
    private event Action _onScroll2;
    private event Action _onScroll3;

    public void Subscribe()
    {
        _onScroll3 += HandleOnScroll;
        _onScroll3 += HandleOnScroll2;
    }

    public void DoWork()
    {
        _onScroll += _ => _onScroll3?.Invoke();
        _onScroll?.Invoke(0);
    }

    public void DoWork2()
    {
        _onScroll2 += () => _onScroll3?.Invoke();
        _onScroll2?.Invoke();
    }

    public void DoWork3()
    {
        _onScroll3?.Invoke();
    }

    private void HandleOnScroll()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(nameof(HandleOnScroll));
    }

    private void HandleOnScroll2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(nameof(HandleOnScroll2));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
_onScroll += _ => _onScroll3?.Invoke();
```

Here a lambda expression is added as a sibscriber to `_onScroll`. If you rewrite this lambda as a method, you will get the following:

```
private void OnScroll(int value)
{
    _onScroll3?.Invoke();
}

public void DoWork()
{
    _onScroll += OnScroll;
    _onScroll?.Invoke(0);
}
```

You could call `_onScroll3` directly: `_onScroll3();`. But what if `_onScroll3` has no subscribers and is `null`? You have to check whether it's `null` before calling. You can simplify things by using safe navigation or you can check for null explicitly and then call directly. But what if `_onScroll3` becomes null after your check and before the actual call? You have to copy the actual value before the check and then call on that value. Compare these 2 examples that do the same thing:

```
_onScroll3?.Invoke();
```

vs

```
var onScroll3Copy = _onScroll3;
if (onScroll3Copy != null)
{
    onScroll3Copy();
}
```

Comment: oh so `_onScroll?.Invoke(0);` actually calls `_onScroll3?.Invoke();`. It was that simple.